# Check if object adheres (not implements) interface

Tags: c#

how can I check if an object adheres/conforms (but not implements) an interface (something like in Google Go: [Interfaces are satisfied implicitly](https://tour.golang.org/methods/5))?

For example:

```
class Foo
{
    void Bar() { ... }
}

interface IBar
{
    void Bar();
}
```

In this case, class `Foo` adheres/conforms implicitly to interface `IBar`...
Is there any way to check this (maybe by Reflection)?

Thanks. :-)

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) an a Library is available : [DeftTech.DuckTyping](https://github.com/deftflux/DuckTyping)

```
bool adheres = DuckTyping.CanCast<IBar, Foo>();
```

[DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) might also help or you may find nuget package from other projects.

This feature is not offered by the language so, as you guess, duck typing libraries are using reflection internally. DeftTech.DuckTyping is open source if you need more details.

Comment: Do you have any example about DynamicProxy? Thanks

Comment: `IBar fooAsBar = DynamicObject(new Foo()).CreateDuck<IBar>();`